# I can' t update/upgrade or install anything

Tags: release-loki, updates, software-installation, appcenter, apt

please, can anybody help me.

after:

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

```
djordje@dj:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
appstream-data-pantheon-icons : Depends: appstream-data-pantheon but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
djordje@dj:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
appstream-data-pantheon-loki-stable appstream-data-pantheon-loki-stable-icons elementary-keyring
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
appstream-data-pantheon
The following NEW packages will be installed:
appstream-data-pantheon
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
36 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/66,2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 74,8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 212677 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../appstream-data-pantheon_0.3.0-0~14~ubuntu0.4.1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking appstream-data-pantheon (0.3.0-0~14~ubuntu0.4.1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/appstream-data-pantheon_0.3.0-0~14~ubuntu0.4.1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/app-info/yaml/pantheon_xenial-extra_amd64.yml.gz', which is also in package appstream-data-pantheon-loki-stable 0.4+r13~ubuntu0.4.1
Processing triggers for appstream (0.11.3-1~elementary0.4.1) ...
AppStream cache update completed successfully.
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/appstreata-pantheon_0.3.0-0~14~ubuntu0.4.1.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)am-d
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8440/apt-get-upgrade-error-because-of-appstream-data-pantheon-loki-stable-icons-0-4

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update the wrong way:

Try using `sudo apt-get update` first to find the newest upgrades. After that use `sudo apt-get upgrade`. If needed, use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` after that and it should work properly.

Comment: I have already done it, and  problem is still there. :/